# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing code to have inputs for a date (day month and year) and how many times they want to repeat the task (what its for.)
I want to use a for loop using times as the boundaries.
Code:

```
def addtimeslot():
    times = int(times_repeated.get())
    print(times_repeated.get())
    variable_end.get()
    day = variable_day.get()
    month = variable_month.get()
    year = variable_year.get()
    fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    name1 = str(name.get())
    minute = int('00')
    second = int('00')
    hour1 = variable_st.get()
    starttimehour = str(datetime.time(hour1,minute,second))
    hour2 = variable_end.get()
    endtimehour = str(datetime.time(hour2,minute,second))
    for i in range(0 , times):
        fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
        cursor.execute( '''INSERT INTO dates (Date, Name, Start, End) VALUES( ?,?,?,? );''', (fulldateadd , name1, starttimehour, endtimehour))
        day = int(day) + 7
        if day > '31':
            month = int(month) + 1
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: You've made `day` an `int` with `day = int(day) + 7` so the test should be `if day > 31:`, i.e. a comparison to an int `31` not a string `'31'`.

Comment: In the future please post the full stack trace so people don't have to guess which line caused the error.

Comment: and that's fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, realised after I posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As questions shouldn't be answered in the comments I'll provide the solving comment of @AChampion:

You've made `day` an `int` with `day = int(day) + 7` so the test should be if `day > 31:`, i.e. a comparison to an int `31` not a string `'31'`